# Cypress testing a Material-UI datepicker is not working

Tags: user-interface, frontend

I'm testing our project with cypress. and it can click the datepicker icon but cannot change date, year, etc.. how can i chage date?

```
    describe('SignUp Page', () => {

        it('go signUP page and input data', () => {
        // Datepicker 
        cy.get('.MuiSvgIcon-root').click();
        cy.contains("[data-handler='selectDay']) a", 25).click();
        cy.get('.MuiPickersMonth-select').click().type('4');
        cy.get('.MuiPickersDay-select').click().type('14');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGQav.png)

I tried

```
    cy.contains("[data-handler='selectDay']) a", 25).click();
    cy.get('[data-cy="2024"]').click
    cy.get('.MuiPickersYear-select').click().type('2022');
    cy.contains('2022').click();
```